# Azure Data Factory Integration Runtime Managed Creation Fails with Terraform - Error: "Failed to create Integration Runtime"

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-factory

I am trying to provision an azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_managed resource using Terraform in my Azure environment, but I keep encountering the following error:

> Error: Failed to create Integration Runtime
> with azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_managed.example,
> on main.tf line 23, in resource "azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_managed" "example":
> 23: resource "azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_managed" "example" {
> The runtime is not able to be created in Data Factory - [Details: The request is forbidden by the IntegrationRuntime API. ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailed ActivityId: XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX]

I have double-checked my permissions, and I am using a service principal with appropriate permissions for the Azure Data Factory. However, the resource creation still fails. Here's my Terraform code snippet:

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_managed" "example" {
  name                = "exampleRuntime"
  data_factory_name   = azurerm_data_factory.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  type                = "Managed"
  location            = "East US"
  description         = "Example Integration Runtime"
  compute {
    type = "General"
  }
}
```

I have already validated my Azure credentials and ensured that the service principal has the necessary permissions. Is there something I'm missing or a specific configuration issue that could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to provision an azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_managed resource using Terraform in my Azure environment and I was able to provision the requirement.

Based on the information provided, it seems that you have already validated your Azure credentials and ensured that the service principal has the necessary permissions. However, you are still encountering an error while creating the `azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_managed` resource using Terraform.

I tried the module which you shared and error mentioned was also incomplete as the configuration does not matches with the latest version. Which may lead to cause the errors more than what you mentioned.

Since the error was related to authentication so double-check that the service principal used in your Terraform code has the appropriate permissions for creating and managing integration runtimes in Azure Data Factory. Make sure it has the necessary roles assigned, such as Contributor or a custom role with the required permissions.Since the Issue was related to service.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demovk"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "storageaccountvk12"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {
  name                = "demovk1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}


resource "azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_blob_storage" "example" {
  name              = "demovksb"
  data_factory_id   = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
  connection_string = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_connection_string
}


resource "azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_managed" "example" {
  name                = "exampleRuntimevk"
  data_factory_id = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
  location            = "East US"
  description         = "IntegrationvkRuntime"
  node_size = "Standard_D8_v3"
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was able to figure out my issue in the module. Thanks